# How to backup from MySQL Ubuntu to Synology NAS MariaDB

Tags: mysql, backup, mariadb, ubuntu

I am facing difficulties when setting up MariaDB on Synology NAS as slave to replicate my server on Ubuntu. But there are missing commands and files (my.cnf) in the installation. Need help on any guidance or instructions! Thanks

Comment: Which MariaDB/MySQL versions are you using? In general a slave/replica needs to understand every replication command of the server. Therefore the replica version of MariaDB probably can handle a MySQL-5.7 server version only ([notable differences](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/incompatibilities-and-feature-differences-between-mariadb-102-and-mysql-57/#incompatibilities)).

Comment: master (mysql): 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
slave (mariadb): 10.3.29-MariaDB

Answer (score 0):

The protocol changes of MySQL-8.0 replication and some of its syntax aren't compatible with any Mariadb version. Recommend looking for options where both master and replica are the same version.

Comment: So what version of mysql and mariadb is recommended?

Comment: With the exceptionally biased disclaimer that I work for MariaDB Foundation, I'd recommend matching the MariaDB-10.3 on your ubuntu-20.04 to match the NAS version using [the repositories of MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/download/?t=repo-config&d=20.04+"focal"&v=10.3). If you have the MySQL-8.0 in use the migration [requires effort and tooling](https://sqlines.com/mysql-to-mariadb) and perhaps another solution is called for like considering a MySQL-8.0 install for your NAS.